# Triple integral in an specific region.

Tags: integration, definite-integrals

I want to calculte the integral $$I=\iiint _W z \ dxdydz$$ where $W$ is
$$ W= \lbrace x>0 , y> 0 , z> 0 : x^2+y^2+z^2<4, x^2+y^2 > 1 \rbrace $$
What would it be the limits of integration? I don't know how to start. Any help is welcome. Thanks in advance

Comment: How about cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: Try spherical coordinates with the order $\phi$ and $\theta$ integrals first.

Comment: What would be the limit of integration in cylindrical coordinates?

Comment: You inequalities are $r^2>1$ and $r^2+z^2<4$. Also, $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$ since $x>0$ and $y>0$.

Comment: It's always a good idea to sketch a picture of the region. Nowadays you can always 3d graphing calculator to plot these regions easily. They really would help you pinpoint the concepts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using cylindrical coordinates $(r,\theta,z)$, the two last inequalities defining $W$ become $r^2>1$, and $r^2+z^2<4$. Moreover, $x>0$ and $y>0$ is equivalent to $0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}$. Therefore,

$$
W = 
\left\{
1<r<2, 0<\theta<\frac{\pi}{2}, 0<z<\sqrt{4-r^2}
\right\}
$$

It follows that

$$I
=
\int_0^{\pi/2} \int_1^2 \int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} rz \ dz\ dr\ d\theta
=
\frac{\pi}{2}\int_1^2 r\ \int_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} z \ dz\ dr
=
\frac{\pi}{2}\int_1^2 r\ \left[\frac{z^2}{2}\right]_0^{\sqrt{4-r^2}} \ dz\ dr
$$

so $I=\frac{\pi}{4}\int_1^2 r(4-r^2)\ dr$. This last integral is the integral of a polynomial function, so is easy to compute.